# Route error in Angular 6/Express

Tags: node.js, angular, azure, express

I'm developping a nodeJS/Angular 6/Express app.
There's only 1 route in express for the "back-end" and many routes for angular.

I have no problems to run that locally but when I try to deploy it on Azure, Angular routes works fine but not back-end routes (which redirect me to the root `url`).

I think Angular is taking priority on back-end routes.

Here are some files :

**server.js :**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const publicweb = './dist/forms';
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(publicweb));


app.use('/api/test', (req, res) => {
   res.send("test");
});

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('index.html', { root: publicweb });
});

const port = '1337';
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`API running on localhost:${port}`));
```

**web.config :**

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
<add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
</handlers>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
            <rule name="Express.js URIs">
      <match url="api/*" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js" />
    </rule>
      <rule name="Angular" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="/*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" 
         negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**package.json :**

```
"start" : "node src/server.js"
```

**app-routing.module.ts :**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { RetailComponent } from './retail/form/retail.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },

 {
    path: 'retail',
    component: RetailComponent
 }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {

}
```

[When I deploy that app on Azure, and I try to access /api/test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkHVY.png)

[My build definition in Azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xy1oU.png)

Many thanks for your answer!

Comment: are you calling `api/test` from a http call? or from a routing call?

Comment: i call that from http

Comment: if you call that from http, you cant get the error in the photo, that error is from routing only

Comment: yes you're right. when I make the call (api/test) in postman, I get the code of my index.html file as response

Answer (score 0):

I think all your get request are mapping to this piece of code

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    enter code here`res.sendFile('index.html', { root: publicweb });
});
```

that is why you are getting `index.html` in your queries to your server.

And `app.use()` is to be used for applying middleware so after middleware work is over the `app.get()` method gets executed and so you get index.html